# How to alter the default "is_invalid error" message in a custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added validate method in rails model for custom validation. But after adding this method i am getting "is_invalid" error message. below is my validate method.

```
     validate :check_quantity_of_offer_bale_insepction

      def check_quantity_of_offer_bale_insepction
        if self.bales_offered_for_inspection.to_i > self.batch_quantity.to_i
          self.errors.add(:batch_quantity) << "Bales offered for inspection should be less than Batch Quantity"

        end
      end
```

I don't know from where "is_invalid" error message is coming from . i want to know how to get rid off this "is_invalid" error message.

Comment: Maybe another validation causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using [the correct syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveModel/Errors/add). Properly written, it would look like this:

```
errors.add :batch_quantity, 'Bales offered for inspection should be less than Batch Quantity'
```

It might be worthwhile to consider using a symbol and [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), instead of a string in the model, for the error message. Not only will it allow for easier internationalization of your application, it will make it compliant with the [Rails 5 syntax](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add).